# Python Flask Heroku Cannot import module

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am getting the following error

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class1'"
```

Structure

```
- hello-world
   - src
       - __init__
       - main
       - class1
- Procfile
```

The `main1` file looks like this:

```
from class1 import G

APP = Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index() -> str:
    return 'We are alive'
```

Profile:

```
web: gunicorn src.main:app --log-file -
```

The heroku logs shows us the following errors:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class1'

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using `pipenv`to install dependencies and it contains `gunicorn`.

Comment: Your PYTHONPATH seems to be `hello-world`, so it should be `from src.class1 import G`.

Comment: You need to change your procfile to `web: gunicorn src.main:APP --log-file -`

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the class using:

```
from .class1 import G
```

Do not forget the dot. When you build a package you have to tell where your class is written using this relative path. This is called intra-package references.

See the corresponding [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

Comment: it fixed my issue on HEROKU @Y0da, but locally it says that that there is no Module `__main__.class1` since src is not a package. I am running locally  with the command `pipenv run python3 src/slack_service.py`

Comment: thanks for helping me, it's related to the same question since it won't fix my issue.  I dunno what you mean, I didn't import the init file.

Comment: @user8569455 what is the error then? The import error should be fixed.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.class1'; '__main__' is not a package`

Answer (score -1):

should be like this

```
from hello-world.src.class1 import G
```

first rename your folder hello-world.. Python does not recognize operands to class name or folder name. it will return an error