# Trigonometric Functions: How do I write Sine and Cosine function's code without using `math` module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigonometry

I have been writing code for a module I am making for my Discord Bot. I have been trying not to use any module as it is not helping in in importing stuff. So I thought I should write the code myself for both of them.

The problem here is that I don't really know how do we make them. I couldn't find them anywhere on the net as everywhere I only saw the use of `math` module which I don't want to use.

I don't know how do I work with them, so I want some help.

Thank You! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have been trying not to use any module as it is not helping in in importing stuff"*?

Comment: @Reti43 I import the module file to the main file of my Bot which I run on Heroku. Now this doesn't work out.

Comment: While I don't know Heroku, if it runs python, it should at least support all the native libraries, of which `math` is one.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav I don't think that has made it any clearer. Do you have some code example which shows why you are having trouble using `math.sin`, for example?

Comment: @L.Grozinger There not a problem in module. But let me tell you. Main file: `a.py` and module file: `b.py`. I have to import `math` in `b.py` to use it but when I stage it to Heroku it would show an error.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you could edit your question to include those extra debugging details, and also add the `heroku` tag?

Comment: If I were you, I would ask about **that** issue (in a different question) and see if that can be resolved, before I decide to roll my own algorithms. Also, are you possibly facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250019/python-flask-heroku-cannot-import-module/46251306) issue?

Comment: It's rather complicated... check here: [How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions)

Comment: @L.Grozinger Yeah. I'l do it in just a while

Comment: @Retu43 Let's forget Inhave any issue. I want to know about their actual wrokng in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971  # Value of constant pi

def f(n):  # Factorial Function
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n - 1)

def deg(x):
    rad = x * pi/180
    return rad

def sin(x):  # Taylor Expansion of sinx
    k = 0
    sinx = 0
    while x >= pi:
        x -= pi
    if pi > x > pi / 2:
        x = pi - x
    while k < 15:
        sinx += (-1)**k * x**(2*k + 1) / f(2*k + 1)
        k += 1
    return sinx

def cos(x):
    cosx = sin(pi / 2 - x)
    return cosx
```

I improved the code now. Now it gives you accurate results of up to 14 decimal places. Also instead of writing full Taylor expression formula, I used a while loop to do that. While loop here acts as a summation function of maths. I also shorten the code inside cos(x). Instead of writing Taylor's expression here, I used a conversion formula of sinx to cosx. Which reduces the calculation process. I made a little change in the code. Now you can calculate sinx of huge number too with the same accuracy.

Comment: It work without adding that `pi` too right?

Comment: Yeah, it works for all radian values of x.

Comment: You can further add a deg function, If you also want to calculate sinx and cosx of any degrees say 45 degree or 30 degree. I edited it into the answer

Comment: Oh, very thank friend. It just really helped me. I think I'll add something like two choices for it either to be degree or radian.

Comment: Your code limits the Taylor Expansion. The below answer actually gives me the loop. I get to use a loop that doesn't really limit me. BUT Your is not wrong.

Comment: I don't understand how Taylor's expansion limits you.  If you elaborate it then I will improve my code so that it gives you the best result.  @Nemanza code is also good but it is accurate to only two places of decimal and mine is accurate to 10 places of decimal.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. I hope it is just what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) you get an approximation up to the desired precision.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/tayser.html

```
def pow(base, exponent):
    return base ** exponent

def faktorial(n):
    value = float(1)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        value = value * i
    return value

def cos(x):
    x = x * 3.14/180
    value = 1
    sign = -1
    n = 200 # precision
    i = 2
    while i < n:
        value = value + (pow(x, i)/faktorial(i) * sign)
        i = i + 2
        sign = sign * -1
    
    return value

def sin(x):
    x = x * 3.14/180
    value = x
    sign = -1
    n = 200 # precision
    i = 3
    while i < n:
        value = value + (pow(x, i)/faktorial(i) * sign)
        i = i + 2
        sign = sign * -1
    return value
```

Comment: This just tells me about the Math side. What about Python?

Comment: You can easily create your own Taylor expansion in Python. As you can see, it's very simple.

Comment: @atru I never really studied Taylor's Expansion you know. It takes time for me understand all of the Maths stuff.